# victorian sounds

Tags: library-sound-effects, effects, period

Hello guys,

Just started working on a victorian horror, typically the audio will need quite a bit of ADR and background/ambience work. I'm wondering if any of you know of any sound libraries around which have been specifically created for this period.

Thanks for any help you can offer

Answer (score 1):

I think sound-ideas sells this one: http://sound-ideas.com/amadeus.html
ok its not 100% victorian, but not far from it:D
Maybe you could go record some yourself, and only buy the atmosphere tracks needed.
What else do you need? Maybe the community can help.

Best wishes

Mikkel

Comment: Thanks, will check it out. I've been watching a few films for inspiration, it's just going to take a lot of work. A bit daunting!

Answer (score 0):

Hollywood edge historical, got some great stuff for period dramas on that library.